# Find duplicate objects in array

Tags: javascript

Need find all transactions that have the same `sourceAccount`, `targetAccount`, `category`, `amount`,
and the time difference between each consecutive transaction is less than 1 minute.

```
  {
    id: 3,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "C",
    amount: 250,
    category: "other",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "C",
    amount: 250,
    category: "other",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z",
  },
];
```

Expected output:

```
[
  [
    {
      id: 1,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "B",
      amount: 100,
      category: "eating_out",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      id: 5,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "C",
      amount: 250,
      category: "other",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      id: 6,
      sourceAccount: "A",
      targetAccount: "C",
      amount: 250,
      category: "other",
      time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
];
```

I started with:

```
const findDuplicateTransactions = (transactions = []) => {
  // Add your implementation here...
  if (transactions.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }
  let result = [];

  for (let item of transactions) {
    for (let checkingItem of transactions) {
      if (
        transactions.indexOf(item) !== transactions.indexOf(checkingItem) &&
        item.sourceAccount === checkingItem.sourceAccount &&
        item.targetAccount === checkingItem.targetAccount &&
        item.amount === checkingItem.amount &&
        item.category === checkingItem.category
      ) {
        if (result.indexOf(checkingItem) === -1) {
          result.push(checkingItem);
        }
      }
    }
  }

  return result;
};
```

Comment: It can be handled by reduce function. I posted my working solution.

Comment: @YaronSchwimmer homework assignment maybe.  But it looks to me like OP put a little effort into it, and the problem isn't that simple.  For example, the best superdev could do with this was an O(n^3) solution that he had to revise 3 times to get right.  And it's actually still wrong, because he didn't sort it by id, so it doesn't match output and there are edge cases that could break it.

Comment: @user120242 I retracted the close vote. thanks

Comment: just for fun, I took the time to solve this problem in an efficient way :)

Comment: @YaronSchwimmer, yes, you're right, it's internship task, and tried do it myself for three days, but using loop in reduce wasn't so obvious for me ;-)

Comment: @AlexBasystyi no need to loop inside reduce. see my answer below

Comment: @YaronSchwimmer, yes, noticed, working fine, thanks for help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a pretty efficient solution. I used a hashmap to group items together efficiently, so the time complexity here is O(nlog(n)) because of the sorting.

```js
let input = [  {
    id: 3,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 6,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "C",
    amount: 250,
    category: "other",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "B",
    amount: 100,
    category: "eating_out",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    sourceAccount: "A",
    targetAccount: "C",
    amount: 250,
    category: "other",
    time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z",
  },
];
const MILLIS_IN_MINUTE = 1000 * 60;

const hashedItems = {};

function itemToHash(item) {
  return `${item.sourceAccount}#${item.targetAccount}#${item.category}#${item.amount}`; 
}

input.sort((a, b) => {
  const dateComp = new Date(a.time) - new Date(b.time);
  return dateComp ? dateComp : a.id - b.id;
});

for (let i=0; i<input.length; i++) {
  const item = input[i];
  const itemHash = itemToHash(item);
  if (!hashedItems[itemHash]) {
    hashedItems[itemHash] = [item];
  } else {
    const last = hashedItems[itemHash][(hashedItems[itemHash].length-1)];
    if (new Date(item.time) - new Date(last.time) <= MILLIS_IN_MINUTE) {
      hashedItems[itemHash].push(item);
    }
  }
}
let result = [];
for (let res of Object.values(hashedItems)) {
  result.push(res);
}
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const findDuplicateTransactions = (transactions = []) => {
  // Add your implementation here...
  if (transactions.length === 0) {
    return [];
  }

  return transactions.reduce((result, x) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i ++) {
        if (result[i].findIndex(item => item.sourceAccount === x.sourceAccount &&
        item.targetAccount === x.targetAccount &&
        item.amount === x.amount &&
        item.category === x.category &&
        Math.floor(new Date(item.time).getTime() / (1000 * 60)) === Math.floor(new Date(x.time).getTime() / (1000 * 60))) !== -1) {
          result[i].push(x);
          return result;
        }
    }
    result.push([x]);
    return result;
  }, []);
};
```

The output:

```
[[{
  amount: 100,
  category: "eating_out",
  id: 3,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "B",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
}], [{
  amount: 100,
  category: "eating_out",
  id: 1,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "B",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
}, {
  amount: 100,
  category: "eating_out",
  id: 2,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "B",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"
}], [{
  amount: 250,
  category: "other",
  id: 6,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "C",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
}, {
  amount: 250,
  category: "other",
  id: 5,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "C",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
}], [{
  amount: 100,
  category: "eating_out",
  id: 4,
  sourceAccount: "A",
  targetAccount: "B",
  time: "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z"
}]]
```